# Why is PHPUnit ignoring assertions when expecting an exception?

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I have a simple unit test case (extensive question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421618/is-this-a-proper-test-case)) on a configuration class that by design triggers PHP errors on type mismatches and undefined configuration settings. In addition to the error, the method is exited returning `false`.

In my test case, I want to have a number of tests that fail. Trouble is, I can't do a simple 'assert' on the return value: Every error thrown during running a test will be converted into a `PHPUnit_Framework_Error` exception.

Now I can make PHPUnit aware that I am expecting an error:

```
/**
 * @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error
 */

public function testSetInvalidKey()
 {
     $this->assertEquals(true, conf::set("invalid_key", "12345"));     
 }
```

This works fine, but what I don't understand is that any additional assertion within that function will *not* be evaluated. Whether it would fail or not, PHPUnit seems to *only* wait for the exception to happen, and be satisfied with the whole function when it has happened.

To wit, this test will run OK:

```
/**
 * @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error
 */

 public function testSetInvalidKey()
 { 
   // The error will be triggered here
   $this->assertEquals(true, conf::set("invalid_key", "12345"));                      
   $this->assertEquals(12345, 67810);   // Huh?    
   $this->assertEquals("abc", "def");   // Huh?
   $this->assertEquals(true, false);    // Huh?

 }
```

Why? Is this the intended behaviour?

I realize you would just separate the assertions into different functions, but I would like to understand the behaviour.

Comment: The behavior you are describing is expected.  Just as throwing an exception would halt the execution of the class under test, throwing an exception halts the execution of the test (until the exception is caught and handled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `conf::set()` is executed within the method `testSetInvalidKey()` the corresponding catch block must be outside. Once caught and logged as the expected exception, I don't see how PHP could resume execution after the first assertion.

Extreme psuedo-code:

```
class Tester
{
  public function run()
  {
    try {
      $test->testSetInvalidKey();
    }
    catch (PHPUnit_Framework_Error $e) {
      // Expected exception caught! Woohoo!
      // How can I continue to run the above method where I left off?
    }
  }
}
```

This type of behavior would be a great proponent to those who believe in the 1 assertion per test axiom.

Answer (score 0):

php unit has the ability to test for exceptions. Take a look at:

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's question; the question is how to continue execution in a test after an exception is thrown.